# How to sum a formula across a range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a spreadsheet to record sales for a Scout fundraiser. I would like to have it be able to calculate the amount each Scout needs to turn in. I have the following spreadsheet set up:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Knh6zNSdP4Vie-vfGGAsVS3TgiXdKPQBvz3rHD0Q2pA/edit?usp=sharing

There is a column for the total due, followed by columns for all of the different products, where a quantity is entered:

| Total Due | Scout Blend | Breakfast Blend | Caballo Columbian Roast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 179 | 2 | 3 | 5 |

I also have a lookup table in a separate sheet for the prices of each item:

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Scout Blend | 17 |
| Breakfast Blend | 20 |
| Caballo Columbian Roast | 17 |

The formula I have right now (to get the total for a single column) is:

`=VLOOKUP($E$1, Sheet3!A1:B50, 2, false) * E2`

I am trying to figure out how to get the total for each row without copying the LOOKUP*QTY formula once for each column (since there are 50 products). Is there a way to accomplish this with Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Went back to it after posting and found what I think is the solution about two minutes later after my continued googling brought me to `ARRAYFORMULA`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VLOOKUP($E$1:$BB$1, Sheet3!$A$1:$B$50, 2, false) * E2:BB2))`

This looks like it works, but going to test it out further to be sure.

Comment: See my proposed solution. However, I also want to note that, as I look at your spreadsheet, the products are held in D:BA and not E:BB (as included in your formula above). If you've added some column to your actual spreadsheet which does not exist in your linked spreadsheet, you'll need to adjust the ranges in my proposed formula accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since your items in 'Final Sales Numbers'!D1:BA1 are an exact match, in order, for the items in 'Price Lookups'!A1:A50, you really don't need to use VLOOKUP at all.

If you like, delete 'Final Sales Numbers'!C:C (including the header) and place the following formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Total Due";IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(D2:BA*TRANSPOSE('Price Lookups'!B1:B50),SEQUENCE(50,1,1,0)))})`

This will produce the header and all results (one form responses begin to come in, of course).

You'll see that whatever is in the 50 columns of 'Final Sales Numbers'!D2:BA can be directly multiplied by the pricing in 'Price Lookups'!B2:B50. `MMULT` then takes those numbers as Matrix 1 and multiplies them by a Matrix 2 made of a stack of 50 1s. Because matrix multiplication is really a two-step process involving multiplying all rows in one matrix by all columns of another and then adding those results, this will give you a row-by-row sum.

Comment: See my comment on your reply post regarding possible range discrepancy.